# Internet problems

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns, ethernet

Today suddenly internet stopped working. Time ago I had to re install ubuntu because each time I ran my system I had to run sudo dhclient. This afternoon internet stopped working, I was connected and could ping gateway or 8.8.8.8 but couldn't google.com. Only setting nameserver 8.8.8.8 on resolv.conf worked but I want to use DHCP, as I was before having to do this and also know why I keep running into this problems, that always come after I update the system. I am currently running ubuntu 22.04.3. Thanks everybody in advance.

This is the output of `ip link show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:eb:f6:3e:ed:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:77:cb:1e:28:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and this the output of `ip addr show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:eb:f6:3e:ed:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.85/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp8s0
       valid_lft 42008sec preferred_lft 42008sec
    inet6 fdc2:3425:2011:e475:4519:b38b:823:10fa/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 1610sec preferred_lft 1610sec
    inet6 fdc2:3425:2011:e475:f39d:d08c:6b3:fb11/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1610sec preferred_lft 1610sec
    inet6 fe80::8862:6c7b:15a2:e9d5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:77:cb:1e:28:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.105/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp6s0
       valid_lft 42012sec preferred_lft 42012sec
    inet6 fdc2:3425:2011:e475:f945:e458:95b3:e74b/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 1611sec preferred_lft 1611sec
    inet6 fdc2:3425:2011:e475:dc3a:153b:cc15:594a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1611sec preferred_lft 1611sec
    inet6 fe80::2709:a3b7:de66:4e92/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is `resolvectl status`'s output:

```
resolvectl status                                                                       ░▒▓ ✔ │ base Py │ at 12:38:51 ▓▒░
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp8s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 80.58.61.250
       DNS Servers: 80.58.61.254 80.58.61.250

Link 3 (wlp6s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 80.58.61.254
       DNS Servers: 80.58.61.254 80.58.61.250
```

If anybody has any idea why this may be happening I would thank the help a lot.

Comment: If you can ping `8.8.8.8` and after setting DNS server to `8.8.8.8` everything works, then your Internet **is** working. Only the DNS resolutions isn't. Either your DNS settings are wrong or maybe the DNS servers you're using (probably those of your ISP) are temporarily down - it happens. Please post the output of `resolvectl status` to show what DNS servers you are using.

Comment: I add it to the question.

Comment: Check first with `ping` if the indicated DNS servers are alive. Then check if they respond to DNS queries with command like eg. `nslookup www.google.com 80.58.61.254`

Comment: They do, and suddenly, after I put the nameserver 8.8.8.8 I got a software update and my resolv.conf file changed completely, now looks like this


nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

Comment: Nameserver 127.0.0.53 is default in Ubuntu; it refers to local `systemd-resolved` daemon, which queries the actual DNS servers. The command `resolvectl status` I mentioned queries the status of that daemon. Comments in default `/etc/resolv.conf` file explain that.
You may have previously messed something in `systemd-resolved` configuration and it isn't able to respond to queries properly. Read carefully `man systemd-resolved.service`, check all the files mentioned there and try to find out what may be wrong.

Comment: No, now it works just fine, as I tell you, after the update everything worked just good. I would just like to know what happened as it is the second time this happens to me